# adding additional animation to bootstrap navbar

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

so i have a bootstrap navbar, i click it and it animates a dropdown of the menu
what i would like to do is once it fully expands, i would like to add a sort fo bounce effect where it continues "dropping down" 10px before coming back up those 10px.

i am still new to using bootstrap in general, so apologies if this is answered somewhere, i did do a fair amount of web searching first.

i am wondering if there is a BS javascript thing i can use such as the "shown" for modals, but i did not find anything.

thanks in advance.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header" id="navBarLogo">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#myPage"><img alt="Piatt TaC logo" class="logo-small" src="images/piattConsultingLogo.jpg"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="#gallery">Gallery</a></li>
                <li><a href="#pricing">Pricing</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks to Gerard for getting me on the right track.
i ended up using the following in my CSS:

```
.navbar-right:after{
  animation: bounce 0.5s
}
@keyframes bounce {
    0% {
        padding-bottom: 0px;
    }
    50% {
        padding-bottom: 30px
    }
    100% {
        padding-bottom: 0px;
    }/**/
}
```